# How to remove a link unwanted border ? when a tag link active

Tags: html, css

My problem is remove dotted border when I click on **a** tag link. After clicking its looks like following type.

[image: img 1]

I also tested in jsfiddle but on there this work perfect not unwanted dotted border draw when I enter image description here click on **a** tag link.

[image: img 2]

Answer (score 3):

#### In old browser versions, css properties inherit from parent properties.

Almost all old browser versions have this problem.

To fix this, add outline properties in your  `<a> tag` and set value `0 none`:

```
a {
   outline: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `none` is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
.classname a{ outline:none;}
```

or

```
a{ outline:none;}
```